# Undefined Symbols?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I have two classes with inheritance at the minute, one is a base class and contains polymorphism, it is the interface:

```
#include <vector>
#ifndef _Signal_h
#define _Signal_h
using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> DIMENTIONS_2;

class Signal {

public:

    Signal();
    Signal(const int N, const int M)
    {
        this->width = N;
        this->height = M;
    };

    virtual vector<DIMENTIONS_2> splitSignal(vector<double> &theData) const = 0;
    virtual vector<DIMENTIONS_2> filterSignal(vector<DIMENTIONS_2>&blocks) const = 0;
    virtual vector<double> returnRawSignal() const = 0;

    virtual int zerocross() const = 0;
    virtual double energy() const = 0;
    virtual int zerocrossmap() = 0;
    virtual bool readSignal() const = 0;

protected:

    vector<double> rawSignal;
    int width;
    int height;
};

#endif
```

And one of the classes that inherits and implements from this:

```
#include "Signal.h"

#ifndef _Audio_h
#define _Audio_h

typedef vector<double> DIMENTIONS_2;

class Audio : public Signal {

  public:

     Audio();
     Audio(const int N, const int M);

     vector<DIMENTIONS_2> splitSignal(vector<double>&data, int N, int M);
     vector<DIMENTIONS_2> filter(vector<DIMENTIONS_2> &data, double sumthres, double zerothres);

     double energy(vector<double> &blocks);

     int zerocross(vector<double> &block);

     int zerocrossmap(vector<double> &strippedData);

     template<typename T>
     int sign(T n);
 };


 #endif
```

The Audio class has implementation (.cpp) but whenever I try to compile using this:

```
g++ Signal.h Audio.h Audio.cpp main.cpp
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Signal::Signal()", referenced from:
>         Audio::Audio() in ccdjMubM.o
>         Audio::Audio() in ccdjMubM.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to compile `Signal.cpp` as well.

Comment: @Mysticial I don't have a Signal.cpp - I thought I could get away with not implementing one since it's Poloymorphic and has no implementation?

Comment: Oh you're right. All the methods are abstract - except the default constructor...

Comment: @Mysticial Does this therefore mean I have to create a Signal.cpp with just the constructor? mhm weird

Comment: `Signal()` was not implemented.

Comment: Or you can just implement it inline in the class.

Comment: @ahenderson See! You know the answer :) Thank you, post it as the answer and I'll accept it! :)

Comment: Stop putting `;` at the end of function definitions! :) Compiler can even give you a warning for that in a strict mode.

Comment: It's killing me that no one else has mentioned, it's spelled "dimension," unless there's a regional spelling I couldn't find.

Comment: @phasetwenty haha just noticed that, damn! bad day i guess

Comment: @VladLazarenko What do you mean? " double energy(vector<double> &blocks);" should have a ";" correct?

Comment: @Phorce: Correct. But that is a declaration, I was talking about a definition as in "double foo() {};", in which case `;` is not needed.

Comment: @phasetwenty: It is Phorce dialect you gramma nazi! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor `Signal()` was not implemented. Just added that and it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The linker is missing the definition (body) of the default constructor for the `Signal` class.

Answer (score 1):

Source files are meant to be compiled while header files are meant to be included.

So, the compile command ought to be:

g++ Audio.cpp main.cpp

In addition, you need to provide an implementation for the default contructor for the Signal class, which can be as simple as

Signal(){};

in Signal.h.